# Laravel Cors bloqueando requisicoes axios

Tags: php, laravel, cors

A configuração do meu laravel cors é esta.

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
```

A configuração da minha requisicao axios é

```
axios.get('http://api2u.oo/api/rede/1', {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    crossdomain: true
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Laravel 5.5.*

O erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou registrar o CORS como sendo um middleware para a api.